# How can I decrease RAM used by Pentaho Server?

Tags: linux, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I do'nt have enough RAM to run Pentaho Server, just 4Gb of ram, now I'm on Linux and I'm running the `ctlscript.sh` file to enable the server but I have others process running and this makes my computer have lag. Any idea about that?

I really need to use this tool but now I don't have chance to buy more Ram in this moment.

I have swap but it is not enough for me.

[EDIT]
I'm just trying to user User console of Pentaho

Comment: Which version you are using ? Community  or paid version ? Why you want to execute ctlscript.sh file , where it is located.. seems like you are doing something not proper ...

Comment: I'm using trail version why?

Comment: This is community forum , so you will get all the answers related with free version here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable plugins you don't need. By default there are a number of plugins installed with Pentaho and if you don't need a particular one you can disable it.

Once you've disabled enough plugins you should be able to decrease the value of the `Xmx` startup parameter on your `start-pentaho.sh` script and it should still work.

Plugins are all installed in your `pentaho-solutions/system` folder. Any sub-folder that has a `plugin.xml` file is a plugin. If you rename that file to anything else (e.g., `plugin.xml.disabled`) it won't be loaded. It's still there if you need to enable it later, but it won't take up any resources.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `start-pentaho.sh`, find the line defining the CATALINA_OPTS variable, and downsize the `-Xmx` [Maximum memory allocated to the JVM].

Then `stop-pentaho`/`start-pentaho`.